# How to use spa from actix_web_lab? It doesn't seem to exist

Tags: rust, single-page-application, rust-cargo, actix-web, cargo-features

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `actix_web_lab::web::spa`
  --> backend/src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | use actix_web_lab::web::spa;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `spa` in `web`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `backend` (bin "backend") due to previous error
```

I already tried this in directory but still did not work:

> ```bash
> cargo add actix-web-lab
> ```
>
> Or add the following line to your Cargo.toml:
>
> ```ini
> actix-web-lab = "0.19.1"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The docs on `spa()` clearly state:

> Available on **crate feature `spa`** only.

So you need to enable this feature. E.g. with `cargo add`:

```
cargo add actix-web-lab --features spa
```

Or by changing Cargo.toml:

```ini
actix-web-lab = { version = "0.19.1", features = ["spa"] }
```